# how to fix (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)") on ec2 bitnami?

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am working on ec2 bitnami with python django on AWS. I am encountering `(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")` while fetching objects from mysql database.

I have been gone through so many forums still I am not getting what is it exactly and why this problem being arisen. Please tell me what is it and how to fix it for python django mysql on ec2 bitnami.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the `HOST` to

> 127.0.0.1

in `settings.py` and make sure MySQL server is running.

Answer (score 1):

In a BitNami AMI the MySQL socket is `/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`

Check the official BitNami documentation here: http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/MySQL#What_is_the_default_configuration.3f

You should change the `HOST` setting accordingly in your settings file:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#host

Comment: /installdir/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock is empty. What i have to write there?

Comment: The MySQL socket should be in `/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`. Otherwise, have you tried to set HOST to 127.0.0.1: `"HOST": '127.0.0.1'`?

Comment: I tried but again its showing error
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")

Comment: You should verify the MySQL server is up and running. Try also to set the HOST setting to localhost: `"HOST": 'localhost'`.

Comment: I tried "HOST": 'localhost' but again showing error (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")